# How to do a left join with STL vector and STL algorithms with time complexity better than O(n^2)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, stl-algorithm

I have 2 vectors, which contain, let's say Person (name, surname, etc) objects. I want to take one of the vectors (let's name it "large") then for each element in this vector find corresponding element in second one ("small") and merge some data from "small" vector element to the "large" vector element. This operation is very similar to left join in SQL terms, but with additional merge of the data. The easiest way is to make 2 cycles, but that will lead to O(n^2) time complexity. Can I do better with STL algorithms?

Comment: You may be able to do better if you switch from `vector` to, say, `multiset`. Using Boost.MultiIndex you can even get O(n).

Comment: @larsmans: or a hashtable (with usual caveats about practical vs theoretical asymptotic performance of hashtables). The hashing function is determined by the definition of "corresponding element", i.e. only hash the field(s) you're joining on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you [sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) the small vector, you can then get O(n log n) for the merge portion by scanning the large vector and use [binary_search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/) to find elements in the small vector.

Comment: And the `sort` part is O(n lg n) as well, so 2×O(n lg n) = O(n lg n) total. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! 
You can do it in O(nlogn) time complexity. Sort the second vector, which takes O(nlogn) time. for each  element in first vector, find corresponding element in second one using binary search (STL has binary_search algorithm) and merge data to the element in first vector. for each element in first vector, we are spending O(logn) time. So the running time complexity of this approach is O(nlogn).

Answer (score 2):

If your lists don't change often, you can sort *both* lists and then do the merge in linear time by simply walking both lists.

If your lists are changing all the time, you're probably better off making the "small" container sorted, such as `map` or `set`. In that case just use `find` on the set for each item in the big list you want to join.